# Hash which can be used to verify one of multiple inputs?

Tags: hash

Is there a hash function `H1` which, when given inputs `a`, `b`, etc., produces output `Z`, and an `H2` which can verify any one of `a`, `b`, etc. when given `Z` like this:

```
H1(a, b) => Z
H2(Z, a) => true
H2(Z, b) => true
H2(Z, c) => false
```

And where Z is (currently thought to be) cryptographically secure (i.e., modifying Z in any knowable way makes H2 return false for any of the provided inputs)?

**Edit:** An additional condition which I forgot to articulate originally. `a` cannot be derived from `b` and `Z`, and `b` from `a` and `Z`. Without this condition, we can just use [Shamir's Secret Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir's_Secret_Sharing), with a `k` value of 1, a randomly generated secret `Z` and `a`, `b`, etc are our `n` values.

Comment: I'd love to see if this can be done.

Comment: I suspect there is no established way of doing this, but I don't see any theoretical reason it can't be done. All I need is an answer from Adi Shamir!

Comment: If you want to keep your assumption, that $H_1$ and $H_2$ are hash functions, then this is very unlikely to exist. Because in this case, $H_2$ could somehow identify partial-preimages of $Z$... Then either $H_1$ is not a cryptographically secure hash function or $H_2$ is not computationally feasible.

Comment: @tylo While I agree that this is quite unlikely to be a secure hash function in the "standard" meaning of the term, I feel that such a thing *is* somewhat similar to a hash function: the goal is comparable in that it is very hard to *obtain* a preimage, but it is easy to check whether a given message *is* a preimage. In this case, the only difference is that it is also easy to verify that something was *part* of the preimage (which is a set), but *only if you already know that thing*.

Comment: That has nothing to do with the term hash function, even without the property *cryptographically secure*. Because what you need to achieve something like that is a trapdoor one-way function.

Comment: @tylo, what I was  something "somewhat similar to a hash function" in the way yyyyyyy describes. I didn't mean something which conforms to any technical definition. Sorry if my choice of words caused confusion.

Comment: This should not end up in a discussion of sorts, but using correct terms is quite important. If an accumulator fits your idea, then that's fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for reminds me of **one-way accumulator functions** [1]. Basically, a one-way accumulator permits to prove the membership of an element $x$ to a set $S$ without revealing the actual members of the set. See for example this definition from [2]:

> The most common form of one-way accumulator is defined by starting
>   with a “seed” value $y_0$, which signifies the empty set, and then
>   defining the accumulation value incrementally from $y_0$ for a set of
>   elements $S = \{x_1,···,x_n\}$, so that $y_i = f(y_{i−1},x_i)$, where $f$ is a
>   one-way function whose final value does not depend on the order of the
>   $x_i$'s. [...] Because of the commutative nature of $f$ ,
>   a source can digitally sign the value of $y_n$ so as to enable a third party to produce a short proof for any element $x_i$ belonging to $S$ [...].
>   A well-known example of a one-way accumulator function $f$ is the
>   exponential accumulator  $exp(y,x) = y^x \mod N$, for suitably-chosen
>   values of the seed $y_0$ and modulus $N$. In particular, choosing $N = pq$ for two strong
>   primes $p$ and $q$ makes the accumulator function $exp$ as difficult to break as RSA cryptography [1].

**Update**: Let's see an example using the $exp$ function defined above. Suppose $a$, $b$, and $c$ are inputs, and that $y_0$ and $N$ are chosen properly. Then the accumulator algorithm $H_1$ will do the following:

1. Compute $s = a \cdot b \cdot c$ and $y = exp(y,s) = y_0^s = y_0^{abc}$
2. For each element $i$ in the input, compute $y_i = exp(y,1/i) = y^{1/i}$. For example, $y_a = y_0^{bc}$.
3. Output $z = (y,y_a,y_b,y_c)$.

Now, if you want to check if some element $x$ belongs to the original collection, you just have to check if for any of the partial results $y_i$, the equation $y = exp(y_i,x)$ holds. For example, if you try with $a$, then equation $y = exp(y_a,a)$ holds, since $exp(y_a,a) = (y_a)^a = (y_0^{bc})^a = y_0^{abc} = y$. On the contraty, if you try with $d$ different to $a$, $b$ and $c$, then none of the equations hold.

The problem with this solution is that output $z$ grows linearly with the size of the set of members.

---

References:

[1] [Benaloh, J., & De Mare, M. (1994, January). One-way accumulators: A decentralized alternative to digital signatures. In Advances in Cryptology—EUROCRYPT’93 (pp. 274-285)](http://www.cs.stevens.edu/~mdemare/pubs/owa.pdf)

[2] [Goodrich, M. T., Tamassia, R., & Hasić, J. (2002). An Efficient Dynamic and Distributed Cryptographic Accumulator*. In Information Security (pp. 372-388).](http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~goodrich/cgc/pubs/accum.pdf)

Comment: For me it reminds Bloom filters. But have no idea how to provide security in this case..

Comment: The problem with Bloom filters is that false positives are possible.

Comment: And that you cannot realistically reduce the false positive probability to something thats cryptographically acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

I can propose this (just invented it on paper): ($h$ is some hash function, like SHA1, $||$ is concatenation, $+$ is usual sum (xor is ok too)):

```
H1(a, b) = (h(a) + h(b)) || h(h(a)) || h(h(b))
```

For H2, either from $a$ or from $b$ we can derive the all $h(a), h(h(a)), h(b), h(h(b))$ and check the hash.

Also, if we assume that input pair is not ordered, to avoid trivial forgery by swapping $h(h(a))$ and $h(h(b))$ we may force order on them (e.g. force $h(a) \le h(b)$, so that $H1(a, b) = H1(b, a)$).

**Intuition** about security: from $h(h(a))$ one can't derive information about $h(a)$ (same for $b$). So attacker can't replace any of $h(a)$ or $h(b)$ in the sum with his hash.

**UPDATE:** I realized it has a simple flaw. Given $H1(a,b),H1(b,c),H1(a,c)$ we can easily get (from sums) $h(a),h(b),h(c)$ and use them to make hashes.

Comment: Though $a$ can't be derived from $b$ and $H1(a, b)$, the attacker can derive $h(a)$ which allows him to forge $H1(a, x)$ for any $x$. This attack may be undesirable.

Comment: I also considered posting a similar answer to this, but it doesn't stand up to the original requirements. It's trivial for an attacker to modify the output such that one of `a` or `b` is validated successfully, but the other is not.

Comment: @StephenTouset how would you do it? if you change $h(h(a))$ then (from first part) $h(b)$ will be corrupted and $h(h(b))$ will not match.

Comment: Ah, actually, you're right. The attack is actually the one you described, where if you *know* one of `a` or `b`, you can forge a verifier for the other. But I don't think that's actually avoidable in the general case: anyone can create `H1(x,y)` for arbitrary `x`, `y`. If an attacker knows one of those values, *regardless of algorithm*, they can forge a verifier for the other. If you need it to be authenticated, replacing the hashes with an HMAC is probably necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, let $H$ be a hash function (in the ordinary sense) from the input space to $[0,2^N)$ for some $N$, and for $0 \leq x < 2^N$ let $f(x)$ be the smallest prime greater than $2^N + x$. (Here $N$ is determined by the security parameter. You can have 'probable prime' instead, where the precise definition of that will also depend on the security parameter.) Then let $H_1(a,b) = f(H(a)) \cdot f(H(b))$, and let $H_2(Z,a)$ be true iff. $f(H(a))$ divides $Z$.

Again, this suffers from the drawback that the image space grows linearly with the number of inputs.

Comment: Very clever, except surely it'd be simple enough to brute-force for false positives - any value which hashes to a value between the smallest prime greater than and the biggest prime less than $2^N + x$.

Comment: Given two hashes $v_{ab} = H_1(a, b), v_{ac} = H_1(a, c)$, attacker can compute $f(H(a)) = gcd(v_{ab}, v_{ac}), f(H(b)) = v_{ab} / f(H(a)), f(H(c)) = v_{ac} / f(H(a))$ and make hashes of any pairs containing $a, b$ or $c$.

Comment: True. Good point!